# Custom form with multiple textarea fields

Tags: 7, forms

How can I create a textarea field in a custom module which has multiple (unlimited) fields? It should be the same result as selecting unlimited amount of values when adding a textarea fields to a content-type.

Comment: you want to create dynamic number of text area in your form?

Comment: Yes, exactly or as close as possible like the function you get if you select unlimited amount of values for a textarea field in a content-type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no property in Drupal's Form API to create multi value fields. You have to create that functionality manually. Check this [tutorial](https://rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms).

[Edit] the tutorial seems to have a couple errors (e.g. the values entered in names are not inherited as default_value when the form is rebuilt when adding a field). But it can give you a general idea on how do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply argiepiano, will hopefully give it a go tonight but it looks like a good starting point :)

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, have been swamped at my other work so haven't had time to try this yet =/